# img class="rounded-circle" is not creating a rounded circle in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap in asp.net mcv application. I want the images to be rounded. therefore used the "img class="rounded-circle". The code is below.

> index.html

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
 }

<h1 class="my-4">
  About Us
  <small>It's Nice to Meet You!</small>
</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <h2 class="my-4 text-center">Our Services</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 text-center mb-4">
    <a href="Application/Search">
        <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="~/Images/search.png" alt="">
    </a>
    <h3>Search App</h3>
    <p>What does this team member to? Keep it short! This is also a great spot for social links!</p>
   </div>

   <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 text-center mb-4">
    <a href="Application/TTS">
        <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="~/Images/text-to-speech.png" alt="">
    </a>
        <h3>Text-to-Speech</h3>
        <p>What does this team member to? Keep it short! This is also a great spot for social links!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 text-center mb-4">
    <a href="Application/SpeechRecognition">
        <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="~/Images/speech-recognition.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
        <h3>Speech Recognition</h3>
        <p>What does this team member to? Keep it short! This is also a great spot for social links!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 text-center mb-4">
    <a href="Application/VAvatar">
        <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="~/Images/virtual-avatar.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
        <h3> Virtual Avatar</h3>
        <p>What does this team member to? Keep it short! This is also a great spot for social links!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 text-center mb-4">
    <a href="Application/VAvatar">
        <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="~/Images/text-to-speech.png" alt="">
    </a>
        <h3>John Smith</h3>
        <p>What does this team member to? Keep it short! This is also a great spot for social links!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 text-center mb-4">
    <a href="Application/VAvatar">
        <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="~/Images/text-to-speech.png" alt="">
    </a>
        <h3>John Smith</h3>
        <p>What does this team member to? Keep it short! This is also a great spot for social links!</p>
  </div>
```

This is how it looks like
[image]

The above code should give a rounded image. But it is still square. Why is this?

Comment: nothing looks wrong over here. Please provide the complete code and relevant screenshots so to identify the problem.

Comment: Provided code and screenshots

Comment: For Bootstrap, you should add `img-circle` and not `rounded-circle`. See the sample [here](https://www.bootply.com/hFIAoymaUw) Give it a try.

Comment: It worked Arul. Thanks.

Comment: img-circle does not work for bootstrap 4.1.1. on an MVC 5 page. Intellisense does not even recognize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Bootstrap, you should add `img-circle` and not `rounded-circle`. See the sample [here](https://www.bootply.com/hFIAoymaUw) Give it a try.